# Umbraco 7 Upload File - Check if remove file is ticked

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have an Upload file option in Umbraco 7, the problem I have is if the remove checkbox is ticked and you click publish to remove the file, my code below catches the upload field as empty and display my custom error message.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlForFileUpload))
                {
                    e.CancelOperation(new EventMessage("Error", "Please select an Excel file before publishing",EventMessageType.Error));
                }
```

[image]

Does anyone know what gets passed to the server so that I can check for it and not display my error message if the checkbox is ticked?

--------------------CancelOperation---------------

[image]

Comment: Have you tried handling the Saving event?: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/events/ContentService-Events

Comment: Hi Mario, Saving does not support e.CancelOperation(new EventMessage("Error", "Please select an Excel file before publishing",EventMessageType.Error)); I can use bubble but in this situation that is not an option

Comment: Are you sure? I just tested that and the SaveEventArgs that is passed to the event handler in fact does have an `e.CancelOperation` method.

Comment: Hi Mario, please see uploaded image

Comment: you can Validate The File Upload Not to be empty

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an event handler to check that. Just make the field mandatory:

[image]